Reusing form for both creating and editing an entity in Askama
Using Askama, I'm trying to create a form template that can be included in both the creation and editing template for an entity (e.g. a blog post). In the former the form would start out empty and in the latter it would be filled with values fetched from the database.
Here's the template I got so far (post is a struct passed into the template, which is None in the case of the creation flow):
{% let action -%}
{% let method -%}
{% let title -%}
{% let content -%}
{% let author -%}
{% if let Some(post) = post -%}
  {% let action = format!("/posts/{}", post.id) %}
  {% let method = "data-hx-put" %}
  {% let title = post.title.as_ref() -%}
  {% let content = post.content.as_ref() -%}
  {% let author = post.author.as_ref() -%}
{% else -%}
  {% let action = "/posts".to_string() %}
  {% let method = "data-hx-post" %}
  {% let title = "" -%}
  {% let content = "" -%}
  {% let author = "" -%}
{% endif -%}

<form {{method}}="{{ action }}">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="title" value="{{ title }}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="content">Content</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="content">
                   {{- content -}}
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="author">Author</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="author" value="{{ author }}" />
        </div>
        <input class=" btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

Writing it this way is very verbose and thus tedious. Is there a better way in Askama to write this?
